# How to enable and verify enforce option in IMA ( Integrity measurement architecture)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, selinux

I am able to enable enforce option in IMA through the following command:

```
  grubby --update-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) --args="ima_policy=tcb ima_policy=appraise_tcb ima_appraise=enforce ima_hash=sha256"
```

I am able to see enforce option after reboot.
Tried to verify the same enforce option following the section "How do I know IMA with appraisal is working?" in the below link :

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Integrity_Measurement_Architecture

But that is not working.Tried with selinux enabled and disabled state.
Is Selinux required for IMA.
Also, extended attributes are not shown for files in root.
Can anyone share the steps to properly enable enforce option for the whole file system and steps to verify the same ?